# Why does a Mongodb collection have more size from PostgreSQL table size

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

I have the same table with the same indexes on Mongodb and PostgreSQL.The table in Mongodb is about 370mb and on PostgreSQL is about 270mb.Why does this happening?Is there an explanation?

Comment: Why do you expect them to be the same? Only a portion of the data stored by the database is the user-specified values.

Comment: @D.SM I don't expect anything.I just want to know why does this happen.I mean what are the reasons that the same table is bigger on mongodb?Is it because of tabular vs json format?indexes? why?

Comment: MongoDB stores more data, or MongoDB stores less data but does it less efficiently, or MongoDB preallocates more space to reduce reallocations in the future and even though it stores less data and does it more efficiently the amount of *allocated* space is larger, or any number of other reasons.